# Russian on-screen keyboard

Tags: 17.10

In ubuntu 17.04 I could use a Russian keyboard on screen. Now in 17.10 when I change to a Russian keyboard the on-screen keys are still in English. How can a get the on-screen keys in Russian?

Comment: Have you installed Russian language? Check it out from `unity-control-center` > `language support`

Comment: Yes, I can type Russian from the physical keyboard but not from the on-screen keys.

Comment: Yes, I can type Russian from the physical keyboard but this keyboard has English lettering on it which makes it difficult to use.  Under 17.04, I could switch to an on-screen keyboard with Russian symbols on it when typing Russian, but 17.10 doesn't seem to offer this. 17.10 seems a backwards step which I now regret installing!

Comment: try this from terminal and check out the onscreen keyboard layout `setxkbmap rs`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it still doesn't work.  When Russian is selected, the screen keyboard still shows English letters but types nothing except the punctuation marks while the physical keyboard types Russian letters.  The 'keyboard layout' popup screen shows the correct Russian letters but the on-screen keyboard doesn't.

Comment: `onboard-settings` -> `keyboard` -> `advanced` tab; change input method

Answer (score -1):

Try [Use an on-screen keyboard](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-osk.html), from Ubuntu's official documentation

Comment: The Ubuntu official documentation doesn't seem to deal with foreign language on-screen keyboards.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to get to onboard-settings in 17.10.